# Pyspark converting RowMatrix to DataFrame or RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I have a square pyspark `RowMatrix` that looks like this:

```
>>> row_mat.numRows()
100
>>> row_mat.numCols()
100
>>> row_mat.rows.first()
SparseVector(100, {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0018, 2: 0.1562, 3: 0.0342...})
```

I would like to run [`pyspark.ml.feature.PCA`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=pyspark.ml.feature.pca#pyspark.ml.feature.PCA), but its [`fit()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=pyspark.ml.feature.pca#pyspark.ml.feature.PCA.fit) method only takes in a `DataFrame`. Is there a way to convert this `RowMatrix` into a `DataFrame`?

Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
row_mat.rows.map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF()
```

Comment: thanks! that was really fast and exactly what I was looking for.